# r purrr problems using walk with save()

Tags: r, save, purrr

I am looking for help using the purrr::walk function with save.

I have a list of four dfs that I want to write to four separate files. This is the code I used and the error I received. Both .x and ... are lists of the same length. I'm sure I'm making some simple error but not sure what that is. Thanks for the help.

```
# load libs
library(purrr)

# create dfs to loop over
df <- data.frame(
  a = rnorm(10),
  b = rnorm(10),
  c = rnorm(10),
  d = rnorm(10)
)
obj <- list(df1 = df, df2 = df, df3 = df, df4 = df )


# create file names to loop over
path <- "/user/home/"
folder <- "RDa/"
names <- c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4")
fnames <- lapply(names, function(x) paste0(path, folder, x, ".RDa"))

# iterate
walk(obj, save, fnames)

Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object ‘.x[[i]]’ not found
```

Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5 tools_3.2.1  Rcpp_0.12.3  knitr_1.12.3
```

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this is to use `walk2` and pass `fnames` in as the second parameter (`.y`) to the function (using `~` to define the function). So replace your last line with:

```
walk2(obj, fnames, ~ save(.x, file = .y))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `imap`, `iwalk`, etc functions were added to `purrr` v0.2.3 in 2017. These take a list, but allow for both list items (with shorthand `.x`) and names (with shorthand `.y`) for iteration.

So in this example, you could create filenames on the fly, such as:

```
iwalk(obj, function(o, name) {
  save(o, paste0(path, folder, name, ".RDa"))
})
```

Or with shorthands:

```
iwalk(obj, ~save(.x, paste0(path, folder, .y, ".RDa")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
iwalk(~ write_csv(.x, file.path("folder_name", paste0(.y, ".csv"))))
```

Comment: This won't work as written since you haven't walked over anything. You're missing the first argument